# Asymptotic Expansions for the Hypergeometric function for large parameters and bounded z?

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

I have stuck on an asymptotic expansion question for the Gaussian Hypergeometric function for large $a$ and bounded $z$ as the following form with $\lambda$ a constant.

\begin{equation}
{}_2F_{1}(a,a+\lambda;a+2\lambda;-z) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

I have found [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sarah_Khwaja/publication/267232610_Uniform_asymptotic_expansions_for_hypergeometric_functions_with_large_parameters_IV/links/5448b9ab0cf2d62c3052b7bb.pdf) reference that may be related to my question,

but they consider a question like this

\begin{equation}
{}_2F_{1}(a+e_{1}\lambda,a+e_{2}\lambda;a+e_{3}\lambda;-z)
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
e_{j}\in {0,1,-1},j=1,2,3.
\end{equation}

So if we could investigate the asymptotic behavior of the above expression $(1)$ for sufficienty large $a$ and bounded $z$?

Thanks a lot for any helpful suggestions!

Best regareds, Liu !

Just one more thing, the worlframealpha tells me that for sufficiently large $a$, the following expression tends to zero for $a$ large but bounded $z$.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Gamma(a+\lambda
)2^{a-1}}{2az^{-a}}{}_2F_{1}(a,a+\lambda,a+2\lambda,-z)\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma$ denotes the gamma function.

And [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Gamma%2832769%2F2%29%2FGamma%2816384%29%2Fsqrt%28pi%29%2F32768%2F%281%2F13%29%5E32768Hypergeometruc2F1%2816384%2C32769%2F2%2C16385%2C-4%C3%976.5%5E2%29) is a WorlframAlpha example of the above integral,

I set $a=32768/2$ and $z=4*6.5^2$ and $\lambda=1/2$ and wa show me that the integral equals $0$.

Comment: Do you mean the standard ${}_2F_1$?

Comment: @LZ981ko The Gaussian hypergeometric function is ${}_2 F_1$ and not ${}_1 F_2$.

Comment: Yes, I have a typo here, I apologize for my carelessness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that $|\arg(1+z)|<\pi$ and that $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ is fixed. By the [known](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1) linear transformation,
$$
{}_2F_1(a,a + \lambda ;a + 2\lambda ; - z) = (1 + z)^{\lambda  - a} {}_2F_1 (2\lambda ,\lambda ;a + 2\lambda ; - z)
$$
Hence, by [$(15.12.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12.E3),
$$
{}_2F_1 (a,a + \lambda ;a + 2\lambda ; - z) \sim (1 + z)^{\lambda  - a} \frac{{\Gamma (a + 2\lambda )}}{{a^\lambda  \Gamma (a + \lambda )}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{q_n ( - z)(\lambda )_n }}{{a^n }}} \tag{1}
$$
as $a\to \infty$ in $|\arg a|\le \frac{\pi}{2}-\delta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, where $(\lambda)_n$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2.iii) and the $q_n ( - z)$ are given by the generating function
$$
\left( {\frac{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}}{t}} \right)^{\lambda  - 1} {\rm e}^{t(1 - 2\lambda )} (1 + z - z{\rm e}^{ - t} )^{ - 2\lambda }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty q_n ( - z)t^n .
$$
You may simplify the expansion $(1)$ further by employing the [known](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E13) asymptotic expansion for the ratio of two gamma functions. If $\operatorname{Re}(z)\ge-\frac{1}{2}$, the expansion $(1)$ applies in the larger sector $|\arg a|\le \pi-\delta<\pi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your constructive answer, Gary! Best regards, have a nice day!

Comment: And if I could further show that (2) is true? I feel extremely grateful for your advisable suggestions. Thanks a lot, Gray!

Comment: What is $\lambda$ in $(2)$?

Comment: Also the expression in your WolframAlpha computation does not match $(2)$. It has more gamma functions in it for instance.

Comment: I set lambda equals 1/2, sorry, I don't describe it clearly

Comment: Well, and here is the newest example of the wa.  <https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Gamma%2832769%2F2%292%5E16383%2Fsqrt%28pi%29%2F32768%2F%281%2F13%29%5E32768Hypergeometruc2F1%2816384%2C32769%2F2%2C16385%2C-4%C3%976.5%5E2%29>

Comment: I have re-edtied the question. Thanks a lot! Best regards! Nice day!

Comment: @LZ981ko Well, the leading-order asymptotics is ${}_2F_1 (a,a + \lambda ;a + 2\lambda ; - z) \sim (1 + z)^{\lambda  - a}$ as $a\to \infty$ in $|\arg a|\le \frac{\pi}{2}-\delta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, provided $\lambda$ and $z$ are fixed. This should be enough for you to proceed.

Comment: Nice day! Thanks a lot, Gary!

Comment: Yeah, I have voted it! Nice day! Best regards!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gary! And one more question, what if I should do to show that $\frac{\Gamma(a+\lambda)2^{a-1}}{az^{-a}}(1+z)^{\lambda-a}\rightarrow 0$? Since I note that $2\frac{z}{1+z}$ might greater than 1?

Comment: Your hypothesis is incorrect. [Try](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28Gamma%5B1000%5D%29*2%5E999%2F2000*Hypergeometric2F1%5B1000%2C1000%2C1000%2C-1%5D) $a=1000$, $\lambda=0$, $z=1$ for instance. The problem is that the Gamma function grows faster than any power.

Comment: Yeah,  in fact, I only need to prove that $\frac{\Gamma(a+1/2)2^{a-1}}{2az^{-a}}{}_2F_{1}(a,a+1/2;a+1;-z)\rightarrow 0$ as $a$ tends to $\infty$ for a  bounded $z$ away from 1

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that the precision of WA was not set high enough. Check [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B%28Gamma%5B1000.5%5D%29*2%5E999%2F2000*3%5E%281000%29*Hypergeometric2F1%5B1000%2C1000.5%2C1001%2C-3%5D%2C40%5D). It shows that it tends to $\infty$ rather than $0$. This is what we expect from the asymptotics as well, since as I said, the gamma function grows faster than any power.

Comment: Yeah, I hope Gary you are right, I checked out that the accuracy of the wa cause the integral tends to zero. And I describe my original question in the last paragraph. Could you give me any advice about how to deal with the above probability? Best regards!

Comment: You should stop expanding the question. Instead, post it as a new, separate one. You can always refer to this one through a link.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I will raise a new question.