# A probability may related to the Gaussian Hypergeometric function and its combination with other special functions.

Tags: probability-limit-theorems, hypergeometric-function

I hope that I should describe the original question rather than the forms after some simplifications.

Given two independent $N$-dimensional Gaussian vectors
$n_{1}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2}_{1}\mathrm{I}_{N})$,
$n_{2}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2}_{2}\mathrm{I}_{N})$.

And I hope to calculate the following probability.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(|n_{1}+n_{2}|^{2}\leq|n_{1}|^{2})\quad (3)
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_{2}<\sigma_{1}$ and $|\cdot|^{2}$ is the $2$-norm.

Intuitively, the above probability tends to $0$ as $N$ tends to $\infty$ since in the high-dimensional space, two independent vectors are almost orthogonal.

And I want to investigate the asymptotic behavior of the above probability when we choose a sufficiently large $N$, i.e., the decreasing speed with $N$ of the above probability. I have also done some numerical experiments to verify that the above probability tends to zero as the increasing of $N$.

And after some calculations I obatin that the above probability equals the following integral.
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(|n_{1}+n_{2}|^{2}\leq|n_{1}|^{2})=\int_{0}^{\infty}\Phi(-\frac{-\sigma_{2}\sqrt{z}}{2\sigma_{1}})\frac{z^{N/2-1}\exp{-z/2}}{2^{N/2}\Gamma(N/2)}dz
\end{equation}
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of the standard Gaussian distribution.

Is the result I obatained correct? If not, what should I do to calculate the correct result of (3)?

And there is a link with the previous question.
[Asymptotic Expansions for the Hypergeometric function for large parameters and bounded z?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4819932/asymptotic-expansions-for-the-hypergeometric-function-for-large-parameters-and-b)

Thanks a lot for any advisable suggestions !